# Как можно получить текст с картинки в телеграмм

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы телеграмм бот обрабатывал отправленную ему картинку с текстом и отправлял текст обратно пользователю.Пробовал прогонять отправленную картинку сначала через opencv ,а потом через tesseract, но данные библиотеки не принимают формат .jpg, который используется в telegram. Как можно вывести текст с отправленной боту картинки?

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types= ["photo"])

def answer_to_photo(message):
    image = message.photo[0].file_id

    img = cv2.imread(image)
    im = Image.open(img)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)
```

После попытки выполнения выдаёт данные две ошибки:

```
 File "shablon.py", line 21, in answer_to_photo
im = Image.open(img)
 File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", 
 line 2884, in open
fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'



2020-07-27 22:09:07,781 (util.py:68 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "AttributeError occurred, 
 args=("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'",)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Родион\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2882, in open
 fp.seek(0)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

Comment: Opencv может работать с jpg

Comment: Проблема кажется в том, что вы в качестве аргумента методу ```imread``` должны передавать путь к файлу, а передаёте его айди

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img = cv2.imread(image)
im = Image.open(img)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

Тут вы (не без ошибок) пытаетесь

- прочитать изображение в формате opencv
- конвертировать его в формат pillow (почему бы не начать читать сразу в pillow?)
- передать его в image_to_string (почему бы сразу не передать имя файла?)

`image_to_string` принимает как pillow изображения (вы пытаетесь передать ему img, а не im), так и имена файлов. Имеем ненужную цепочку конвертаций... Just `text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)`, okay?

Вывод: работайте над именованием переменных. image - file, img - cv_image, im - pil_image. Сами же себя и запутали.

### FWD

По поводу первого исключения. Во-первых вы неправильно конвертируете opencv изображение в pillow. [Правильно так.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232813/convert-opencv-image-format-to-pil-image-format/48602446) Во-вторых AttributeError говорит о том, что opencv вернул не изображение, а None, ибо не смог его прочитать. Возможно, я ошибочно предположил, что в image было имя файла с изображением, потому что я то знаю, что первым аргументом идет оно, но вы, возможно...

Answer (score 0):

Не получиться ведь тессеракт находится в локальном а то что он получает фото в глобальном нужен другой метод например онлайн сервисы по типу гугла со своим клауд читалкой а за это придется заплатить

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 260, in run_tesseract
raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error, cannot read input file C:\Users\user\photo: No such file or directory Error during processing.')

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).